# $B \subset A$ and dim $A$ = dim $B$ means $A$ an integral extension of $B$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm referring here to the Krull dimension. Is this necessarily true for commutative rings with unity? How about for finitely-generated $k$-algebras?

Comment: Consider localizations of B.

Comment: I don't really know any theorems about localization and integral extensions.

Comment: no need of theorems, just try with simple examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider any transcendental field extension.  Trancendental implies that it's not an integral extension and all fields have Krull dimension $0$.

Comment: Ah, silly me. Should have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It is also false for finitely generated $k$-algebras, consider for example $k[x] \subseteq k[x,x^{-1}]$. Or just take $A \hookrightarrow A^n$ for some $A \neq 0$.